# Cannot assign 'import class' because its an import - Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have been initializing some constant classes as

```
    export class A {
       foo: string,
       b: B
    }

    export class B { 
       bar: number
    }
```

And then importing them into another class and initializing them in another file. However, if I have issues using class B when I want to initialize class A.

Example:

```
    import { A, B } from '../models/class';
    export const myVariable: A = {
       foo: 'FOO',
       b: B = {
          bar: 5
       }
    }
```

the first assignment is correct. However, the B class inside A will give me the error - *Cannot assign to 'B' because it is an import.*

Comment: You forgot } at the end

Comment: Do `A` and `B` have to be classes? If you only need them for their types, it'd make much more sense to make them `interface`s and you make `b: {...} as B`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This isn't how you assign a value to a property in an object literal:

```
{
  foo: 'FOO',
  b: B = {
    bar: 5
  }
}
```

Basically you're trying to assign an object to `B` *itself* instead of to the `b` property on your object, and then trying to assign the *result* of that assignment to the `b` property.  Which doesn't really make sense.

You're probably getting confused over the usages of the `:` character.  When declaring a variable in TypeScript, it's used to indicate the type.  When defining an *object literal* in JavaScript (and therefore also TypeScript), it's used to define a value for an object's property.

This is how you define an object literal:

```
{
  foo: 'FOO',
  b: {
    bar: 5
  }
}
```

Comment: thanksfor the clarification