# How do I reset my class after every test?

Tags: typescript, class, jestjs, ts-jest

I would like to reset a class assigned to a const after every test.

In main.ts I have a class and assign it to a const:

```
class MyClass {
  // many properties and methods inside here
}

const myClass = new MyClass()
```

Now I would like to reset this to a fresh class after every test I run. This will be done with the built in function afterEach() from jest. I tried to just assign it like this:

```
main.myClass = new MyClass()
```

but typescript is complaining `Cannot assign to 'myClass' because it is a read-only property.`

What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

It's because of 'const' keyword in your

```
const myClass = new MyClass()
```

You can rewrite it as (in typescript)

```
let myClass : myClass = new MyClass();
```

Then when you want to reset it you just do

```
myClass = new MyClass();
```

Comment: I just followed your steps. I changed in main.ts from const to let. Now if I wanna assign the new class to it in my test file it says: Cannot assign to 'myClass' because it is an import.

Comment: Not much I can gather from the question what's wrong but try googling that error and see where u went wrong. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69454926/cannot-assign-import-class-because-its-an-import-javascript

Comment: Sorry I did a mistake in my code. After changing it to a let it is still telling me `Cannot assign to 'myClass' because it is a read-only property.`